# How to refactor my imports with typescript aliases?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, tsconfig

I want to rename my import statements from

```
import {config} from "./../../../common/config";
```

to

```
import {config} from "@common/config";
```

the tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@aws-lambda-powertools/logger": ["node_modules/@aws-lambda-powertools/logger"],
      "aws-sdk": ["node_modules/aws-sdk"],
      "tslib": ["node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"],
      "@common/*": ["../common/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

so it is set in the paths, but when i run a test with Jest it fails with error:

*Cannot find module '@common/config' from 'functions/index.spec.ts'*

Weirdly this worked on the frontend in Angular. But now on the backend in NodeJS it's not that simple.
Does anybody have an idea what i'm missing?

I followed this instruction: [Use typescript aliases to clean up your import statements](https://medium.com/slackernoon/use-typescript-aliases-to-clean-up-your-import-statements-7210b7ec2af1)

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

> Note that this feature does not change how import paths are emitted by tsc, so paths should only be used to inform TypeScript that another tool has this mapping and will use it at runtime or when bundling.

You need to use some other package for it to work in runtime, e.g.:

- [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths)
- [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)